# log shifting failed. comparison of Fixnum with String failed

Tags: ruby, logging

I am trying to use the ruby logger. I am getting the error: `log shifting failed. comparison of Fixnum with String failed` and I do not understand why.

This is my code:

```
require 'logger'
require 'yaml'
require 'net/ssh'

logger = Logger.new('/tmp/log.log', 10, 'daily')
logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

Net::SSH.start(host, user, forward_agent: true) do |ssh|
  output =  ssh.exec! "cat #{app}/shared/config/database.yml"
  ssh.loop
  logger.debug output

  stuff = YAML.load(output)
  logger.debug stuff['database']

  ssh.loop
  ssh.close
end
```

The error message seems to be implying that its expecting a Fixnum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new):

> ```
> new(name, shift_age = 7, shift_size = 1048576)
> new(name, shift_age = 'weekly')
> ```

So I think you use the constructor with the wrong arguments.

Try:

```
logger = Logger.new('/tmp/log.log', 'daily', 10)
```